# pip install private repository with private dependencies via HTTPS

Tags: python, git, pip, package, python-poetry

I'm trying to pip install a private repo via HTTPS in CI (GitHub Actions). It needs to be HTTPS because the org want to use authorised tokens to set permissions rather than ssh keys. I can do this with the following:

```
BASIC_CREDENTIAL=$(echo -n x-access-token:$repo_pat_token | base64 -)
git config --global http.https://github.com/.extraheader "Authorization: basic ${BASIC_CREDENTIAL}"
pip install <repo_a>[option] -e git+https://github.com/<org>/<repo_a>#egg=<repo_a>
```

And this works, unless `repo_a` has a dependency defined that's also a private repository (`repo_b`) installed by ssh, which in this organisation, is the case.

`repo_a` depends on several other private repos which are defined in a Poetry `pyproject.toml`, containing the following:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
<repo_b> = {git = "ssh://git@github.com/<org>/<repo_b>", branch = "main"}
```

So the problem is: when I try to install `repo_a`, it tries to use ssh to install `repo_b` and fails:

```
Running command git clone -q https://github.com/<org>/<repo_a> 
Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@github.com/<org>/<repo_b>'
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
WARNING: Discarding git+ssh://****@github.com/<org>/<repo_b>@main. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q 'ssh://****@github.com/<org>/<repo_b>'  Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've tried using .insteadof (highlighted [here](https://gist.github.com/taoyuan/bfa3ff87e4b5611b5cbe)) to no avail, same behaviour.

Note: I'm actually using Conda to install from an environment.yaml with pip dependencies, but I don't think Conda is the problem, as underneath it's pip running git clone commands.